# How to suppress link tracking for a single link in Exacttarget?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have included a link to a google docs form in an email template in ExactTarget (Marketing Cloud). The url looks like this:

```
https://docs.google.com/a/xxxxxxxx/forms/d/e/xxxxxxxxxx/viewform
```

ExactTarget adds tracking info to the end of the link and changes it to something like

```
https://docs.google.com/a/xxxxxxxx/forms/d/e/xxxxxxxxxx/viewform?cm_lm=email@example.com&cm_ainfo=&%%__AdditionalEmailAttribute1%%&%%__AdditionalEmailAttribute2%%&%%__AdditionalEmailAttribute3%%&%%__AdditionalEmailAttribute4%%&%%__AdditionalEmailAttribute5%%
```

This makes it an invalid Google forms link and I get the error message **Resource Unavailable**

**Is there any way I can prevent ExactTarget from adding tracking info only to this link in the email and still track all other links?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have an issue with your [**Web-Analytics Connector**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/web_analytics_connector/) configuration.  Those Additional Email Attribute variables should be proceeded by an `=`.

I would contact SFMC Support and have them send you what's configured.

Under normal circumstances, it shouldn't break the link.